# Keeping a service persistent by calling startService from the onDestoy method

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service doing some background job that should continue running as long as until some particular condition within my app changes. I have used the START_STICKY flag.

However, the Android system will still terminate the service if it requires resources.

I thought of a work-around. I thought of calling the startService method from the onDestroy method (based on an internal condition being met in my app) so that when the android service terminates this service, it will restart if required by my app.

Will this work? Is this harmful to the device in any way?

Comment: If the OS requires resources for some task which it deems more important, I don't think it will work

Comment: `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called, hence any logic you intend to use in it is unreliable. If you've used `START_STICKY` flag then your service should be restarted instead of being destroyed completely. If its not restarting, then you may be at fault else where.

Comment: Would creating an asynctask within the service to handle my work help make it more persistent?

Comment: You should not focus on how to keep your service alive all the time, just figure out why your service is not restarting. If you're performing some network tasks or heavy operations then you should use multi-threading like asynctask.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to monitor incoming calls, would using asynctask be a better option here?

Comment: Since service has no user interface, which means no Orientation change issues, yeah you can use an Asynctask. Asynctask has limitations when used in Activity or Fragments.

Comment: Ok thanks for the input. The service for the most part runs when app is not running. When the activity is running however, I have used the flag necessary in Android manifest to work for orientation issues.

Comment: Orientation changes don't effect service, so no need of that flag

Comment: @SharpEdge : When I resort to this approach, things work, but it is draining battery very quickly. I am making the service listen to incoming phone calls, in the asynctask, and using a polling loop, upon whose completion, I am releasing resources. How can I structure this in a more efficient way?

Comment: `A service running all the time == fast battery drainage` no matter what... Might i suggest you change your design, i.e use a broadcastReceiver in your app to listen for call state changes, when call state changes your application will catch the broadcast then you can do anything during/after call

Comment: @SharpEdge : Will the broadcast receiver always be alive?

Comment: @SoulRayder you can then start a service from broadcast receiver.. which should perform the tasks you need for example, call state changes, broadcast is fired, your application gets it, you then check whats the call state, if its on call, then start your service.. then when call disconnects another broadcast will be fired by the system, your application will get it then you'll check the call state again, if its disconnected then stop the service. Hope you're getting me here

Comment: Ok will definitely try this :) Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: @SharpEdge : Thank you so much for your last input. You literally made my app a 100 times more efficient. If you generalize ur comments and post an answer, I would be sure to accept and upvote it :)

Comment: The pleasure is all mine in helping you bro. How about I post my comments as an answer so that you can upvote and accept it eh ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A service running all the time == fast battery drainage` no matter what... I suggest you change your design, i.e use a `BroadcastReceiver` in your app to listen for call state changes, when call state changes your application will catch the broadcast then you can do anything during/after call.

You can then start a service from broadcast receiver.. which should perform the tasks you need for example, call state changes, broadcast is fired, your application gets it, you then check whats the call state, if its on call, then start your service.. then when call disconnects another broadcast will be fired by the system, your application will get it then you'll check the call state again, if its disconnected then stop the service. Hope you're getting me here.